# Tikz Graph with bended arrows (annotations)

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I have a tikz graph with bend arrows and somehow tikz draws the arrow annotation (in my case just numbers) on the arrow. This happens a lot more often when the arrow is bend. It seems that tikz has no knowledge of where the annotation is with respect to the arrow. I have the self-contained code below. What I want is that annotations are above the bending and also I want to have a minimum distance (in pixel?) to the arrow that I can control. Is there something like that in Tikz?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.5cm,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,fill=blue!10,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

    % nodes
    \node[main node] (A) {A};
    \node[main node] (B) [below left of=A] {B};
    \node[main node] (C) [below right of=A] {C};
    \node[main node] (D) [below right of=B] {D};
    \node[main node] (E) [right of=C] {E};
    \node[main node] (F) [above of=E] {F};

    % lines
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
       (A) edge [bend right] node [right] {0.0} (B)
       (B) edge [loop left] node {0.0} (B)
           edge [bend right] node [right] {0.0} (D)
           edge [bend right] node[right] {0.0} (C)
       (C) edge [bend right] node [left] {0.0} (A)
           edge [bend right] node [left] {0.0} (B)
           edge [bend left] node [left] {0.0} (D)
           edge [right] node [right] {0.0} (E)
       (D) edge [loop below] node {0.0} (D);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just replaced some "right" and "left" to "above" and "below"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.5cm,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,fill=blue!10,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

    % nodes
    \node[main node] (A) {A};
    \node[main node] (B) [below left of=A] {B};
    \node[main node] (C) [below right of=A] {C};
    \node[main node] (D) [below right of=B] {D};
    \node[main node] (E) [right of=C] {E};
    \node[main node] (F) [above of=E] {F};

    % lines
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
       (A) edge [bend right] node [right] {0.0} (B)
       (B) edge [loop left] node {0.0} (B)
           edge [bend right] node [right] {0.0} (D)
           edge [bend right] node[below] {0.0} (C)
       (C) edge [bend right] node [right] {0.0} (A)
           edge [bend right] node [above] {0.0} (B)
           edge [bend left] node [left] {0.0} (D)
           edge [right] node [above] {0.0} (E)
       (D) edge [loop below] node {0.0} (D);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]